# Django Query Foreign Key

Tags: python, html, django

I have a tag model which have a category for each tag:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=35)
   description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=255)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I also have a user & tag relation model:

```
class UserTag(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='User', related_name='user_tag')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, verbose_name='Tag', related_name='user_tag')
    preferred = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Preferred', default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Updated at', auto_now=True)
```

How can I query all distinct categories names for a specific user?

Comment: What Django code have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming name column in categoty model

```
list(set(UserTag.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('tag__category__name',flat=True))
```